# jQuery: Creating multiple event listeners at once?

Tags: jquery

```
  $( document ).on({
    "mousewheel": scrollHandler,
    "DOMMouseScroll": ("onmousewheel" in document) ? null : scrollHandler, // Firefox
    "keydown": keyHandler,
    "mousedown": function( e ) {
      if( e.button === 1 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
```

I know this code is listening for a scroll down, but I am really sure how it works. According to the [documentation for on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) the function accepts the arguments `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`. However, in the example code I provided there is a hash being into the on() method. Which parameter is that supposed to be?

Is this code essentially creating multiple eventListeners at once or is there something else going on I do not understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the format of the jQuery `.on()` method being illustrated the first parameter is a plain javascript object with the keys of the object being "event names" and their values being functions that are executed if an event of that type occurs.  In your example, if a `mousewheel` event is detected, a function called `scrollHandler` will be called.  If a `keydown` event is detected, a function called `keyHandler` will be called (etc etc).

This technique is merely a shortcut for having multiple `.on()` statements one after the other.

Comment: Cool, thanks. In this context, can you also explain how, "("onmousewheel" in document) " works?

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 Happy to my friend.  This is what is called a "ternary" expression.  First is a boolean expression followed by two values with a "colon" between them.  If the boolean expression is true, the whole value is value1 else value2.  In practice, this fragment of code asks "If we have a property in the document object called "onmousewheel" then set DOMMouseScroll to have no handler otherwise set DOMMouseScroll to be handled by the function called scrollHandler.

Answer (score 1):

Your use corresponds to the [second](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data) calling signature of `.on`:

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ] )
```

The description of `events` is:

> Type: PlainObject
>   An object in which the string keys represent one or more space-separated event types and optional namespaces, and the values represent a handler function to be called for the event(s).